# "But there is one more (question) that I daresay you are burning to put to myself; and that is, what your own name is doing in this place"

Tags: symbolism, robert-louis-stevenson, the-wrecker, lloyd-osbourne

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, [Epilogue, passage 425/427](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Epilogue), published 1892)

(Passage 425)

> **But there is one more (question**; *added by me*) **that I daresay you are burning to put to myself; and that is, what your own name is doing in this place**, cropping up (as it were uncalled-for) on the stern of our poor ship? If you were not born in Arcadia, you linger in fancy on its margin; your thoughts are busied with the flutes of antiquity, with daffodils, and the classic poplar, and the footsteps of the nymphs, and the elegant and moving aridity of ancient art. **Why dedicate to you a tale** of a cast so modern;—full of details of our barbaric manners and unstable morals;—full of the need and the lust of money, so that there is scarce a page in which the dollars do not jingle:—full of the unrest and movement of our century, so that the reader is hurried from place to place and sea to sea, and the book is less a romance than a panorama—in the end, as blood-bespattered as an epic?
>
> . . .

(Passage 427)

> I see you staring. Here, you will say, is a prodigious quantity of theory to our halfpenny worth of police novel; **and withal not a shadow of an answer to your question**.
>
> Well, some of us like theory. After so long a piece of practice, these may be indulged for a few pages. **And the answer is at hand.** It was plainly desirable, from every point of view of convenience and contrast, that our hero and narrator should partly stand aside from those with whom he mingles, and be but a pressed-man in the dollar hunt. Thus it was that Loudon Dodd became a student of the plastic arts, and that our globe-trotting story came to visit Paris and look in at Barbizon. And thus it is, dear Low, that your name appears in the address of this epilogue.
>
> For sure, if any person can here appreciate and read between the lines, it must be you—and one other, our friend. All the dominos will be transparent to your better knowledge; the statuary contract will be to you a piece of ancient history; and you will not have now heard for the first time of the dangers of Roussillon. Dead leaves from the Bas Breau, echoes from Lavenue's and the Rue Racine, memories of a common past, let these be your bookmarkers as you read. And if you care for naught else in the story, be a little pleased to breathe once more for a moment the airs of our youth.

Did anyone read the *Epilogue* of *The Wrecker*? In some respect it puzzles me. The *Epilogue* is the last chapter of the novel *The Wrecker*. Its title is "To Will H. Low". I suppose this name to have a figurative meaning - in a sense, these words and the pronunciation of "H" are ambiguous, aren't they!? Why is this **"tale dedicated to"** Will H. Low? And why **"is the answer at hand"**, what *is* the answer? In the sentences . . .

> It was plainly desirable, from every point of view of convenience and contrast, that our hero and narrator should partly stand aside from those with whom he mingles, and be but a pressed-man in the dollar hunt. Thus it was that Loudon Dodd became a student of the plastic arts, and that our globe-trotting story came to visit Paris and look in at Barbizon. **And thus it is, dear Low, that your name appears in the address of this epilogue.**

. . . the author gives reasons but they don't mean anything to me - the real reason isn't specified in my opinion. The whole thing doesn't make any sense to me actually. Who is Will H. Low;  why is it **"that his name appears in the address of this epilogue"**? Is it because he hasn't been mentioned up to now? What **"is"** Will H. Low's **"name doing in this place"**?

Comment: https://www.adirondackdailyenterprise.com/opinion/columns/2018/12/the-stevenson-bookplate-by-will-h-low/

Comment: RLS addressed the epilogue to his friend, the (real) painter Will Low. [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Hicok_Low) Low specialised in scenes from Greek mythology, so it appears incongruous to dedicate a story of modern life to him, but RLS had chosen to make his hero an artist who got involved in the action of the story by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP noted, the Epilogue of *The Wreckers* is dedicated to "Will H. Low". [Will Hicok Low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Hicok_Low) was an American artist and a personal friend of Stevenson. As the Epilogue explains, Stevenson used Low as a model for the character of Loudon Dodd:

> It was plainly desirable, from every point of view of convenience and
> contrast, that our hero and narrator should partly stand aside from
> those with whom he mingles, and be but a pressed-man in the dollar
> hunt. Thus it was that Loudon Dodd became a student of the plastic
> arts, and that our globe-trotting story came to visit Paris and look
> in at Barbizon. And thus it is, dear Low, that your name appears in
> the address of this epilogue.

This is explained more clearly in Low's book of reminiscences, *[A Chronicle of Friendships, 1873-1900](https://archive.org/details/chronicleoffriend00loww/page/434/mode/2up?q=wrecker)*. Stevenson had written to Low asking his permission to dedicate *The Wrecker* to him, acknowledging the debt he owed to him, but due to the vagaries of the postal service to Samoa, Low never received it. In a later letter that Stevenson sent to Low's wife, RLS explains:

> The point is this: Loudon Dodd, the narrator of the tale, is drawn a
> good deal from the degenerate W. H. L. (*i.e. Low)* : some of his
> adventures and some of mine are agreeably mingled in the early parts,
> and the thing might seem too near the truth for him to care about the
> connection. See that he bears this sheet to the truculent Bulingame,
> by which he (the T. Blgme.) is authorized to communicate "The
> Wrecker," and do you see that he (the degenerate W. H. L.) answers it.

The letter to which RLS wants an answer is for Low to give permission. Given that some aspects of Dodd's life are based so firmly on his life, RLS was concerned that Low may not want the connection to be advertised.

Low mentions how he had told RLS various anecdotes which were used in T*he Wrecker*:

> In its earlier numbers [*The Wrecker* was first published serially in
> a magazine, so this refers to the first installments] I had recognized
> many of the adventures of Loudon Dodd in Paris as based, with
> differences, upon experiences that were common to Stevenson and
> myself. Some incidents came closely home to me; others, of which I had
> been witness, I had poured into the receptacle of his retentive
> memory, while still others were the common knowledge of "the quarter"
> in our time. All these had passed through the alembic of his
> imagination sufficiently to remove any trace of violation of private
> knowledge, and had thus become fairly characteristic of the life he
> described.

Several of these incidents are described in the Epilogue, "the dangers of Roussillon. Dead leaves from the Bas Breau, echoes from Lavenue's and the Rue Racine, memories of a common past". The "dangers of Roussillon", for example, refers to an incident in Paris when RLS and Low got drunk on too much Rousillon, and got lost seeking their rooms afterwards, similarly to the events described in chapter 2, "Roussillon Wine".

So the mention of Low in the Epilogue is to thank him for the help he gave to RLS in providing inspiration for the character of Loudon Dodd.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fine answer. I much appreciate your help. All questions and problems are ironed out now.